# populate spinnerB with one of two arrays (from string.xml) from the users choice of spinnerA

Tags: android, eclipse, android-spinner

I have been working on this all night and I am in a brain fog.  can anyone give me a code snipit that would help I currently have this to populate SpinnerA onCreate:

`ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterTypeGas = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.TypeGas, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterTypeGas.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerTypeGas.setAdapter(adapterTypeGas);`

R.array.TypeGas has two choices "Propane Gas" or "Natural Gas".  depending on what the user selects I want SpinnerB to use either R.array.NaturalGas or R.array.PropaneGas.  My problem is that the spinner is populated at create how do I change it so it is not populated until after SpinnerA onItemSelected?   Thanks for your help.  I am fairly new to developing so if you could be detailed in your answer that would be great.

after implementing the code from "RastheDestoryer" i get an error at "createFromResource" of the ArrayAdapter for spinnerB.  the error is:  The method createFromResource(Context, int, int) in the type ArrayAdapter is not applicable for the arguments (CSSTPipeSizingActivity.OnGasSelectedListener, int, int).  In my main.xml file I have to specify an array for spinnerB (that array is stored in my strings.xml file) uses.  I think this is the problem, because in my code I am telling it a different array.  Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that I ended up using:

```
public void main program () {
...
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterTypeGas = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.TypeGas, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterTypeGas.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerTypeGas.setAdapter(adapterTypeGas);

    //Sets up the spinnerPipeLength spinner 
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterPipeLength = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.PipeLength, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterPipeLength.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerPipeLength.setAdapter(adapterPipeLength);

    // Listens for changes in the selected item in each spinner 
    spinnerTypeGas.setOnItemSelectedListener(new GASOnItemSelectedListener());
    spinnerSupplyPressure.setOnItemSelectedListener(new    SupplyOnItemSelectedListener());
    spinnerPipeLength.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
...
} // end mainprogram()

public void SpinnerNatGas() {
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSupplyPressure = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.NaturalGas, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterSupplyPressure.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerSupplyPressure.setAdapter(adapterSupplyPressure);
    adapterSupplyPressure.notifyDataSetChanged();
} // end SpinnerNatGAs ()

public void SpinnerProGas () {
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSupplyPressure = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.PropaneGas, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterSupplyPressure.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerSupplyPressure.setAdapter(adapterSupplyPressure);
    adapterSupplyPressure.notifyDataSetChanged();
} // end SpinnerProGAs ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an onitemSelected listener to the overall class

```
public class OnGasSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
     long id) {
    //set all of spinnerB adapter stuff here

    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
}
```

and add the listener to spinnerTypeGas

```
spinnerTypeGas.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnGasSelectedListener());
```

onitemselected will be triggered right after the spinner is built and every time the user changes the selection

Answer (score 0):

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
    Spinner chooseproject,choosetask;
    public static ArrayList<String>projectnameList,propanegasList,naturalgaslist;
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
    projectnameList=new ArrayList<String>();
    propanegasList=new ArrayList<String>();
    naturalgaslist=new ArrayList<String>();
    projectnameList.add("Propane Gas");
    projectnameList.add("Natural Gas");
propanegasList.add("p1");
propanegasList.add("p2");
propanegasList.add("p3");
propanegasList.add("p4");
propanegasList.add("p5");
naturalgaslist.add("n1");
naturalgaslist.add("n2");
naturalgaslist.add("n3");
naturalgaslist.add("n4");
naturalgaslist.add("n5");

    chooseproject=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.chooseproject_dropdown);
            choosetask=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.choosetask_dropdown);
     chooseproject.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> projectName=new ArrayAdapter<String>  
                (this,R.layout.dropdow_spinner_dropdown_item,projectnameList);
                projectName.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                chooseproject.setAdapter(projectName);
     choosetask.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            switch(arg0.getId())
            {
            case R.id.chooseproject_dropdown:

                String ProjectName=chooseproject.getSelectedItem().toString();



                  if(ProjectName.equalsIgnoreCase("Propane Gas")
    {
     ArrayAdapter<String> projectTask=new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (this,R.layout.dropdow_spinner_dropdown_item,propanegasList);
                    projectTask.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    choosetask.setAdapter(projectTask);
    }
    else
    {
    ArrayAdapter<String> projectTask=new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (this,R.layout.dropdow_spinner_dropdown_item,naturalgaslist);
                    projectTask.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    choosetask.setAdapter(projectTask);
    }
    }


                break;
            case R.id.choosetask_dropdown:   

                String ProjectTaskName=choosetask.getSelectedItem().toString();

                break;
            }  


        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I believe this is what I was looking for.  I have a bug in the rest of my code so I am debugging it, then I will be able to confirm.  I did have to change the all the ArrayAdapter<string> ... R.layout.dropdow_spinner_dropdown_item to R.layout.main

Comment: After debugging my code this method did not work, for some reason spinnerB is still getting data from the strings.xml file at run time.  I want it to wait until a choice is made from spinnerA and then load either arrayA or arrayB from the strings.xml file.  Thanks for your work it helped me organize my coding better.